# JMETER - Variable Header doens't be automated

Tags: javascript, java, jmeter

I'm testing an API, and at some point, one function creates a TOKEN, and I need that token on HEADER for the next function to work. I search and tried everything but without success.

**This is my environment**
[image]

Here, under the POST CREATE MODEL I have:

**Bean shell preprocessor**
[image]

This is for the function Bearer

**HTTP manager**
[image]

This is my HTTP manager, where I need a token.

**Here is the big token, it's because have a lot of bytes?**
[image]

If I put a token manually, work, but I need that automated. And I can't do that. Someone can help this poor QA intern?

Ty guys <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the Beanshell PreProcessor (moreover [since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting)](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting), just HTTP Header Manager will be sufficient assuming that your `EXTRACTOR Token` really extracts the token, check your `${auth_token}` variable value using [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener combination

Just in case here's how I would use [JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor/):

[image]